# Performance improvement for mongo count query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The `mongoTemplate.count(new Query(), getCollectionName())` API eventually runs an aggregation and it sometime takes more than 3 minutes to run form mongod logs.

Code : https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c65df051095a5000188be30#L218

```
[{
        $match: {}
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: 1,
            n: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The collection on which the count is ran can have too many writes(insert, delete) and reads (count, read documents from collection) in parallel from multiple nodes/threads. That could be the reason for the slowness.

As a fix, I am planning to use the `estimatedDocumentCount` API

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection(getCollectionName()).estimatedDocumentCount()
```

But I am worried that the estimatedDocumentCount might not be accurate all the time, and that can add some drawbacks to the system.

Another option is to use `find` API by projecting only "_id" fields and then get the size of the list.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("_id");
mongoTemplate.find(query, getConcreteClass(), getCollectionName()).size()
```

But, the collection can sometimes have more than a million records. Every customer has a separate tenant databases and all of them can have 0 to 2M records in their database. If we use the above find query approach, there might be a scenario that multiple customers data are loaded at the same time and that might cause an OutOfMemoryError in java.

Is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Comment: have you indexed your documents?

Comment: There is no filter applied, hence no index required. But yes, there are in total 3 indexes in the collection.